# Custom adapter size 0 after notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I have a ListView, an ArrayList and an MaterielAdapter that extends ArrayAdapter. My problem is that calling notifyDataSetChanged() won't update my ListView... I spent 3 hours trying all similar issues on SO but none was efficient for me.

```
private ListView lvMateriels;
private ArrayList<Materiel> materiels = new ArrayList<>();
...
lvMateriels = new ListView(this);
lvMateriels.setAdapter(new MaterielAdapter(this, R.layout.object_line,materiels));
...
materiels.add(new Materiel());
((MaterielAdapter)lvMateriels.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My collection has all the objects but listview never refreshes, nor the adapter...

Comment: Post your adapter, please.

Comment: the object you changed is not updated in your adapter class, is it?

Comment: You're not even using that adapter?

Comment: I renamed it to ask the question, I put adapters like this one in separate files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found out solution**

My problem was that I was setting my ArrayList another ArrayList

```
materiels = getMateriels() // getMateriels() returns an ArrayList<Materiel>
```

It seems that setting a new object to the list doesn't work, what I finally did is the following :

```
materiels.clear();
materiels.addAll(getMateriels());
```

And by the way for those who need to have a header into their ListView, you have to do like :

```
((YourAdapter)((HeaderViewListAdapter)yourListView.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks!, you nailed it. I was doing the same. Don't know why we can't just do list = newlist and call NotifyDataSetChanged(), though...

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not even adding the ListView to the activity view. Instead of doing new Listview(this), I'd recommend you to define a listview in your layout xml
Something like:

```
 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/listview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then in your activity:

```
lvObjects = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not that dumb, I did added it.

Comment: Ok..... it's the only weird thing I saw, but without the rest of the activity it's kind of hard to tell what's going on

Comment: Although I've had similar problems in the past, and sometimes I've solved those re-defining the array before modifying it and calling notifyDataSetChanged.. Although that shouldn't be needed...

Comment: That could be useful, i'll try it tomorrow, my activity is 2k lines long and I didn't have time to take only the useful parts thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

Stock your adapter, and your adapter will be your list too.

```
MaterialAdapter adapter = new MaterialAdapter(this, 
R.layout.object_line);

lvObjects = new ListView(this);
lvObjects.setAdapter(adapter);
...
adapter.add(new Object());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Currenlty your adapter, do not know that he need to use the list that you pass in argument. But you extends ArrayAdapter, that means that your adapter is a list.

Comment: Store * ;) et non le problème ne vient pas de là Raphael, en fait si tu veux tout fonctionne très bien sauf cette foutue fonction notifyDataSetChanged... en fait dans la classe où je liste les matériels, j'ai mon ArrayList dont le contenu change à plusieurs endroits et à chaque fois j'appelle notifyDataSetChanged sur mon adapter, qui est censé se mettre à jour par rapport à la liste que je lui ai attribué, mais ça ne veut pas.. alors que quand je reset l'adapter ça fonctionne bien, et la suppression se fait très bien ...

Comment: D'accord, mais déjà dans ton exemple, tu utilise `ObjectAdapter` et tu nous comme adapter `MaterielAdapter`. Et c'est un forum uniquement en anglais (je sais que mon anglais est pas excellent), mais on n'est forcé de parlé en anglais.

Comment: J'ai anonymisé pour rendre l'exemple plus simple, en réalité tu l'auras compris object = Materiel

Comment: Si tu veut resté dans la configuration actuelle, Override `getCount()` et return materiels.size();

Comment: J'ai déjà essayé :/

Comment: Ta essayé ce que j'ai mis en réponse ?

Comment: Cet après midi oui :/

Comment: Mes ton XML aussi pour voir